# Vim execute script on write

Tags: terminal

Ok i used " :term perl" in vim and it opened a horizontal split window (embedded terminal) with my perl code in the other split window. I like now to execute the perl code by simply saving the file (:w) and have vim output to the embedded terminal. What is the command for this.

Comment: You can set up an `autocmd`. `:h autocmd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find it easier to not do this with vim, specifically, but with a tool that does this kind of thing well. Then I don't have to worry about scripting vim's relatively complex terminal API to send commands to the right place at the right time.

I use [entr](https://eradman.com/entrproject/) for running commands.

So, in whatever terminal you have, I would do something like

```sh
echo script.pl | entr -rcs 'perl $0'
```

or similar, based on the man page for `entr` and what your needs are. A handy technique is to pipe `git ls-files` in, though that won't help if you create a new file; it won't be in the watch-list. For that I usually just re-start `entr` itself (after quitting with `q` or `C-c`) with `!!`.